# Is the volume change during a phase change quasistatic?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to justify the use of $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$ for the change in entropy instead of the more generic $dS=\frac{dU}{T}$.

According to Schroeder, in order to do so, one has to confirm that the volume change occurs quasistatically.

Consider for example a phase change with a volume change, i.e. ice melting. It is known that the volume of the same mass of ice and water is distinct. Is that volume change quasistatic?

Cheers

Comment: Since when is dS=dQ/dT?

Comment: thanks, edited!